# uniform convergence of a function (continuous or differentiable or both?)

Tags: continuity, uniform-convergence

I have a function $S$:

$$ S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{x+n^2} \\ \text{for} \ x \ge 0
$$

I need to determine if $S$ is continuous or differentiable or both.

Answer (score 1):

Because
$$
\frac1{x+n^2}\leq\frac1{n^2}
$$
the partial sums converge uniformly from Weierstrass test, hence $S(x)$ is continuous.

Because
$$
\left(\frac1{x+n^2}\right)'=-\frac1{(x+n^2)^2}
$$
we can again use Weiestrass test to the derivatives, obtaining that $S(x)$ is differentiable.